# Reserve specific core for python script PYTHON RPi3 RASPBIAN

Tags: python, process, raspberry-pi, raspbian, cpu-cores

Hello I'm running some python script on Raspberry Pi3. I noticed strange behaviour. Let's assume that I run this python script and it use specific core for example 3. (RPi3 have 4 processing cores). I noticed that from time to time this code is running on other core. There is an option to set up it to use all the time just one core without switching them from time to time ?

Comment: I'm curios, what would be the reason to force the script to run on the same core everything it's runs?

Comment: @MichaelAbabio low latency IO